# How to pass a field from a NSManagedObject to a controller to modify it

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a NSManaged Object that contains several string fields, like :

```
@interface myObject : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * name0;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * name1;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * name2;
```

I have a table view controller that displays the properties of this object and when someones clicks on a cell, it calls a second view controller (EditTableViewController below) that will allow to modify this particular cell. I would like to pass this second controller the NSString* it needs to modify (depending on the cell clicked).

Therefore I tried something like this for the second controller :

```
@interface EditTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic) NSString *value;
```

and in the implementation part I have (among others) :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    EditPropertyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EditPropertyCell"];
    cell.valueTextField.text = self.value;
    cell.valueTextField.delegate = self;
    [cell.valueTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    [cell.valueTextField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.value = textField.text;
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
    return YES;
}
```

The first controller owns a reference to an object of type myObject

```
@interface myObjectDetailTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) myObject * myObject;
```

and calls this second controller through :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    EditTableViewController *etvc = [[EditTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    if ([indexPath row] ==0) {
        etvc.value = self.myObject.name0;
    }
    if ([indexPath row] ==1) {
        etvc.value = self.myObject.name1;
    }
    if ([indexPath row] ==2) {
        etvc.value = self.myObject.name2;
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:etvc
                                     animated:YES];
```

}

The problem it that it doesn't work, i.e. when I am in the EditTableViewController I can correctly see the value I want to modify (e.g. name0) but then if I modify it is not saved. I guess the NSString* has been copied somewhere but I can't figure out where. I wonder whether it has do with NSManagedObject ?

Anyway, maybe the way I am trying to do this is completely inappropriate in which case I would also be happy to know what would be the best approach to do it

(in particular, later on I would like ideally to be able to also set fields that were set to nil that way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just pass the string, because you need to tell the managed object that the string is changing and you do that by calling the managed object setter method for that property.

A better option is to pass both the managed object and the string which is the key that should be changed. Your controller can then use the key to get the existing value to display and set the value for that key to update the managed object (which then needs to be saved to store the update).

Comment: To be sure I understand : do you mean I should pass the string "name0" or "name1" to the controller  (not the associated property) and then let the controller use this string to understand what method of the managed object it needs to access ?

Comment: Well, I guess that was it -- at least it works very well that way. It seems a bit unelegant though that I have to do a case distinction on the value of the string I am carrying around in my controller but maybe there are no better options ? Thanks a lot anyhow.

Comment: Case distinction? No, use KVC -`valueForKey:` takes the name of the property as a string

Comment: Ok, I didn't know about KVC. Now it's perfect ! thanks